# API documentation RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

For my first API documentation (very simple API, only one method) I have more or less this structure:

```
                           API documentation

1.Disclaimer
2. Using the API
2.1 Input data -> Here I explain how should be the input data, JSON
2.2 Output data > Here I explain which data should be obtained and in JSON
2.3 Example -> I am giving an example of my input and output
```

In 2.3 I explain that the output (real example in my documentation, I post here only a structure of how it looks) should look like this:

```
{"message":"Succesful ","data":{"batt1":{"value1":977.48279000017,"value2":977.4208279000022,"value3":1034.9372639500002,"value4":2534.854048049996,"value5":2465.145176450681,"value6":2465.1451764508347},"batt2":{}...}
```

But its missing me how to put the request in this example. 
Until now I have been using/ testing my API with this command: `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '@alldata.json' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/namecontroller`

Should I put in my documentaion in 2.3 something like this:

In this example I used the cURL command in the following form: `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '@alldata.json' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/namecontroller`

Sorry I am very new to all this, RoR,API etc...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can show it in below format so that will be easy to understand

```
url: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/namecontroller
method: POST
Body : @alldata.json
```